# java index of 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Having problems using 2 dimensional arrays.  I have something like this:

```
List<List<String>> pmValues = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> pmList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to add values from pmValues based on the index of pmList if it is equal to another value (layerrate):

```
for (something) {
    String layerrate = Something;
    String value = Something;

    for (int aa = 0; aa < pmList.size(); aa++) {
        int abc = aa;
        String abc2 = pmList.get(aa);
        for (int bb = 0; bb < pmValues.size(); bb++) {
            if (layerRate.contentEquals(abc2)) {
                pmValues.add(bb, value);   --> it doesnt save??? error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need something like this, I ran the code but seems not working as I need to get the index of pmList to use it to save the values from pmValues in the same index as pmList.

```
pmList: A
pmValues (values): A1, A2, A3, A4
pmList: B
pmValues (values): B1, B2, B3, B4
pmList: C
pmValues (values): C1, C2, C3, C4
```

Anyone have any idea? ty

Comment: what is the point of `List<List<String>>`, if you want to map A to A1,A2.. then why not use `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 2):

If I follow your question you need to `get` the inner List,

```
pmValues.add(bb, value);
```

should be something like,

```
if (pmValues.get(aa) == null) {
  pmValues.set(aa, new ArrayList<String>());
}
pmValues.get(aa).add(bb, value);
```